# Support and Subscribe Plugin for WordPress recommendation

Tags: wordpress, subscribe

I'm looking to offer online services using my WP site.
Every time a user pays the subscription his WP account is promoted to a special user role for example subscriber and every subscriber can create tickets using WP.

So I'm looking for one or more plugins that can handle the Paypal payment, then upgrade user to susbcriber and let him create,edit and reply support tickets.

When user subscription ends then he wont be able to access the ticket system unless he renews his subscription.

Comment: Good question. :) However StackOverflow is not the website for this kind of questions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

makmour.

I would really consider s2memeber/ s2member pro.

the normal is a free and really great membership plugin I've used it for several years now. pretty solid.
[s2member](http://www.s2member.com/)

its really easy to run and their support is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks Neta.I just stumbled on s2member too.
I will give it a try and update my question as a reply.